# session_start in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

my code below shows the percentile analysis for the number of sessions started for those users who uninstalled in the last 30 days. How can I change this analysis to include only the users who did NOT uninstall in the last 30 days, and used the app in the last 30 days?

```
with removed as (
   
SELECT distinct user_pseudo_id as removed_users
from `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
where event_name = "app_remove"
 
and

DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), DAY)
BETWEEN DATETIME('2023-04-22 00:00:00')
    AND DATETIME('2023-05-21 00:00:00')
)
,
counts as(
select user_pseudo_id,  count(event_name) as event_countss
    from `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
    where event_name='session_start'
    and user_pseudo_id in (select * from removed)
    group by user_pseudo_id
)

select
 
  percentiles[offset(25)] as p25,
  percentiles[offset(50)] as p50,
  percentiles[offset(75)] as p75,
 
from (
  select approx_quantiles(event_countss, 100) percentiles
  from counts
 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code below by replacing the subquery with a subquery that selects only users who did not uninstall in the last 30 days and used the app in the last 30 days.

```
with active_users as (
  SELECT distinct user_pseudo_id as active_users
  from `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
  where event_name = "session_start"
    and DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), DAY)
      BETWEEN DATETIME('2023-04-22 00:00:00') AND DATETIME('2023-05-21 00:00:00')
    and user_pseudo_id not in (
      SELECT distinct user_pseudo_id as removed_users
      from `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
      where event_name = "app_remove"
        and DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), DAY)
          BETWEEN DATETIME('2023-04-22 00:00:00') AND DATETIME('2023-05-21 00:00:00')
    )
),
counts as (
  select user_pseudo_id, count(event_name) as event_countss
  from `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
  where event_name='session_start'
    and user_pseudo_id in (select * from active_users)
  group by user_pseudo_id
)
select percentiles[offset(25)] as p25,
       percentiles[offset(50)] as p50,
       percentiles[offset(75)] as p75,
from (
  select approx_quantiles(event_countss, 100) percentiles
  from counts
)
```